# Can't access the value of int in a double list sml

Tags: list, if-statement, sml

I cant access the value of int*int inside a double list

```
fun fnd(xs:(int*int)list list)=
    if null xs
    then 0
    else #2 xs
```

example i input

```
fnd [[(1,2)]];
```

i want to print the second value which is `2`

Comment: `xs` is a list of lists of pairs, not a pair. Use pattern matching.

Comment: If you really need to use accessors, what you're looking for is "the second element of the head of the head of `xs`". The translation to SML is straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value you are passing to `fnd` is a list of lists of tuples. You appear to wish to get the second value from the first tuples in the first list. This is best accomplished with pattern matching.

```
fun fnd([[(_, x)]]) = x
  | _ = 0
```

The second pattern `_` matches any value that wasn't previously matched.

Notte that this is not an especially useful way to return. What if the list passed in is `[[(1, 0)]]`. This would return `0` as well and the caller of this function would not know which had happened: was the list empty, or did it find the value?

Returning an option type would convey that.

```
fun fnd([[(_, x)]]) = SOME x
  | _ = NONE
```